# integral of the product of a trigonometric and an exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Since tan has an odd power I would normally aim to sub $u=\sec(x)$, but I cant get rid of the $2^x$.
$$\int 2^x \tan^9(x^2)\sec(x^2)dx$$

I also tried integrating by parts but it got more complicated.

Comment: Do you have a reason to expect this has an elementary antiderivative?

Comment: How does $u=\sec(x)$ relate to $\sec(x^2)$?

Comment: @AlexBecker it is one of the questions on my Calc 2 mock test that I could not answer.

Comment: @Infodayne I'm going to go ahead and guess that $2^x$ should be $2x$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Ya im starting to think the test had a typo. If its 2x then I would sub u=x^2. It also could have been (x^2) = (2^x),,, trying to solve that right now.

Comment: Even just $\int 2^{x} \sec x \tan x dx$ involves a hypergeometric function, according to WolframAlpha; I'm pretty sure we still don't cover that in Calculus II... (I think it's safe to say that $2x$ is what was intended in an exam at that level.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the posted question (the $2^x$ should probably be $2x$ as discussed in the comments). However, I hope my solution will be still be instructive to those who happen to come across this question anyway:

$$\int 2x\tan^9(x^2)\sec(x^2) \, dx$$ We first start by simplifying the argument in the tangent and secant terms. Let's make a $u$-substitution where $u = x^2 \implies du = 2x \, dx$. So we have
$$ \int \tan^9(u)\sec(u) \, du$$
It takes some practice to see what another substitution should be. It has to do with the *parity* [even-ness vs. odd-ness] of both the powers of the tangent and secant. Click [here for Pauls Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralsWithTrig.aspx), or [here](http://www.math24.net/integration-of-some-classes-of-trigonometric-functions.html) for some more general approaches to these types of integration problems along with examples. Anyway, the appropriate substitution is $v=\sec(u) \implies dv = \sec(u)\tan(u) \, du$ and we're left with $$\int \tan^9(u)\sec(u)\, du \\ = \int \tan(u)\tan^8(u)\sec(u)\,du \\ = \int \tan^8(u)\sec(u)\tan(u)\,du \\ = \int [\tan^2(u)]^4\sec(u)\tan(u)\,du \\ = \int [\sec^2(u)-1]^4 \sec(u)\tan(u)\,du \\ = \int [v^2-1]^4 \, dv$$
At this point it's just expanding into a polynomial, which is always welcome when it comes to integration:
$$ \int [v^2-1]^4 \, dv \\ = \int [(v^2-1)(v^2-1)]^2\,dv \\ = \int [v^4-2v^2+1]^2\, dv \\ = \int (v^4-2v^2+1)(v^4-2v^2+1)\,dv \\ = \int (v^8 -2v^6+v^4-2v^6+4v^4-2v^2+v^4-2v^2+1)\, dv \\ = \int (v^8 -4v^6 + 6v^4-4v^2+1)\,dv \\ = \frac{1}{9}v^9-\frac{4}{7}v^7+\frac{6}{5}v^5-\frac{4}{3}v^3+v + C$$
But we know $v=\sec(u)$, and that $u=x^2$ from earlier. So we know $v=\sec(x^2)$. Let's back-substitute and replace all the $v$'s with $\sec(x^2)$ to get:
$$ \frac{1}{9}\sec^9(x^2)-\frac{4}{7}\sec^7(x^2)+\frac{6}{5}\sec^5(x^2)-\frac{4}{3}\sec^3(x^2)+\sec(x^2)+C$$